# PHP Connection statement for SQLserver

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I have a SQL server on MS azure. Using a php file and some basic select statements (eg. select * from table) I have been able to grab data from the database, so I know my details are correct.

However when I put a connect statement in any other files the page appears blank.  For example, any form submission pages.

This is the connect statement I have:

```
<?php
$myServer = "hostname";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "dbname";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
?>
```

I'm sure it's probably something simple but I have tried loads of different ways and nothing seems to work, I don't even get an error message to work with.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Hi, do you have any update now?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line in your `php.ini`.

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

To locate your `php.ini` file, add this code below at the top of your php script

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am a beginner.  I cannot find that file.  Where is it?

Comment: I don't think I can access that file as my website is hosted on azure.

Comment: Then you would need to contact your hosting provider to make sure you have the extension installed

Comment: And don't use `mssql_connect` and etc. it is removed and cannot be used in PHP 7.0.0. Use `PDO` or `sqlsrv`. Use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check for `PDO drivers`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access the php.ini using MS azure, do you think there is any other way I could get this working?

Comment: @sd0093 create page `phpinfo.php`. Add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and save. In browser go to `http://yoursitehere.com/phpinfo.php` and check for `PDO`. Search `PDO drivers ` - what is in `enabled` field?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure environment doesn't install `php_mssql.dll` extension, it installs `php_sqlsrv.dll` instead.

You can leverage **Console** tool in Azure portal and execute `php -m` to check all the preinstalled modules in Azure PHP runtime:
[image]

You can use PDO in PHP to handle sql server database, such as the following connection test:

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:garysql.database.windows.net,1433; Database = garymbdata", "gary", "QWEasdzxc123");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
        die(print_r($e));
    }
```

Additionally, we can configure PHP configuration settings on Azure Web App beside modifying php.ini directly. Also we can install `mssql.dll` extension on Azure Web App if you insist on.

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure for more info.